# i get error in xcode 8.3 swift 3. error 200 is issue related to url. ?

Tags: iphone

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>http://tempuri.org/'>slsl
error 200
[image]
**i get  error in xcode 8.3 swift 3. error 200 is issue related to url. ?**